# Strange behavior string.Trim method

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, trim

I want to remove all spaces(only `' '` and `'\t'`, '\r\n' should stay) from string. But i have problem.

Example:
if i have

```
string test = "902322\t\r\n900657\t\r\n10421\t\r\n";
string res = test.Trim(); // res still "902322\t\r\n900657\t\r\n10421\t\r\n" 
res = test.Trim('\t'); // res still "902322\t\r\n900657\t\r\n10421\t\r\n"
```

But if i have

```
string test = "902322\t";
```

`Trim()` work perfectly. Why this behavior? How i can remove `'\t`' from string using `Trim()` method?

Comment: No, `test.Trim()` will return `"902322\t\r\n900657\t\r\n10421"`. I've just tried that on csharppad.com. Please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - I suspect you're misdiagnosing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method deals only with whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the string

So you should use [String.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string test = "902322\t\r\n900657\t\r\n10421\t\r\n";
string res = test.Replace("\t", String.Empty); // res is "902322\r\n900657\r\n10421\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Trim()` removes edge characters. It seems you want to remove characters anywhere in the string, which you can do by:

```
test.Replace("\t", null);
```

When you pass `null` as the replacement value, it simply removes the old value. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If newValue is null, all occurrences of oldValue are removed.

Also note that you can *chain* calls to `Replace`:

```
test = test.Replace("\t", null).Replace(" ", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim only removes the white spaces from the beginning and the end of the string. So because the first String ends with \r\n, which apparently aren't considered white spaces, Trim doesn't sees anything to remove. You can use Replace to replace the spaces and tabs from the string. For example:
`test.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "");`